# Json Parsing on swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, parsing

Hi I am quite new to iOS programming. I have to login using an api and get "member data" and display it. 
Here is what I have till now :

```
 @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {


       let usr = usernameTextField.text
      let pwdCode = passwordTextField.text
let iturl = NSURL(string: "something?UserName=\(usr!)&Password=\(pwdCode!)")


            let session = URLSession.shared
              var request = URLRequest(url: iturl as! URL)
            do {

                let auth = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: login, options: .prettyPrinted)
               request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                   request.httpMethod = "POST"
                    request.httpBody = auth

                let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                    print("Got data \(data)  response: \(response)with error \(error)")
                    print("Done.")
                })task.resume()
```

**In the response I am getting this**

```
 Got data Optional(41 bytes)
response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000228760> { URL: something } { status code: 200, headers {
        "Cache-Control" = "s-maxage=0";
        "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
        "Content-Security-Policy" = "referrer origin-when-cross-origin";
        "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        Date = "Mon, 19 Jun 2017 07:08:33 GMT";
        "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
        Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
        "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
    } }) with error nil
Done.
```

Here is the Json response the url gives :

```
{  
   "nonprimary":null,
   "memtier":[  

   ],
   "memcard":[  
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "type":"Membership_card__c",
            "url":"/services/data/v37.0/something"
         },
         "Effective_End_Date__c":"2018-04-13",
         "Effective_Start_Date__c":"2017-04-13",
         "Member__c":"a0A2800000Psomething",
         "Id":"a0B28000something"
      }
   ],
   "member":{  
      "attributes":{  
         "type":"Member__c",
         "url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/something"
      },
      "Contact__c":"0032800000wk79XAAQ",
      "Enrollment_Channel__c":"Web",
      "Registered_date__c":"2017-04-13",
      "Name":"something",
      "Member_Image__c":"<img src=\"https://ap2something" width=\"300\" height=\"281\"></img>",
      "Member_Number__c":"000000974",
      "Membership_Card__c":"a0B2800000IJPn7EAH",
      "Member_Tier__c":"Ruby",
      "Member_Type__c":"Individual",
      "Points__c":1656009,
      "Program__c":"a0G2800000jXisqEAC",
      "Status__c":"Active",
      "Tier__c":"a0P2800000AKJxMEAX",
      "Id":"a0A2800000PM4DlEAL"
   },
   "contact":null,
   "account":{  
      "attributes":{  
         "type":"Account",
         "url":"/services/datasomethingSZyxAAH"
      },
      "Name":"something",
      "FirstName":"somethingd",
      "LastName":"somethingir",
      "PersonEmail":"somethingr@gmail.com",
      "PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail":false,
      "PersonMailingStreet":"something ",
      "PersonBirthdate":"1992-07-19",
      "Passport__c":"JHdd546TG",
      "PersonMailingCountry":"Saudi Arabia",
      "PersonMailingCity":"Jeddah",
      "PersonMobilePhone":"+9667887575763",
      "National_ID__c":"P435345",
      "PersonDoNotCall":false,
      "Id":"0012800001FSZyxAAH"
   }
}
```

**This is what my final implementation should have :**

Hi (person name) ,your card number (member card) you are type (Member_Type__c) and have points (Points__c)

Could someone please point me to a tutorial or give me some resource to know how to implement the next step?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `JSONSerialization()` to transform the `data` (and not `response`) into JSON. Then the JSON it's just Dictionary and Arrays.

Comment: Do you mean when I print it? I edited to add it . I just get "41 bytes"

Comment: @user161993 you are asking full code form us instead of that you should try something 1.Parse you data using JSONSerialization. 2. Search how to get specific key values from json.

Comment: No, I dont want the implementation in a copy paste at all. I just want know what my next step should be. thank you.

Comment: @user161993: you should try to decouple ViewController code and network request code, by using delegation

Comment: @3000 how would that help? As I am new to this, I would like an explaination to make me understand it better

Comment: @user161993: the ViewController is only a Controller in the MVC pattern. This means you should not make requests from a Controller but you should create at least a Network class to manage client-server communication. You can start here and then search other resources: https://news.realm.io/news/slug-marcus-zarra-exploring-mvcn-swift/ (search for "massive viewcontrollers", for example)

Comment: @3000 okay so this will like a best practice right? thank you. I will keep this in mind the next time. However, this wouldnt help my scenario right now, or would it?

Comment: @user161993: it helps organizing your code from the start. For example, you should never put all that code into a button.   :-)  Anyway, there are tons of examples and tutorials showing you all the code, just search a little   :-)

Comment: Yes i will make a function and call it on the button. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to get members details then you can try this example. Sorry I used your file instead of URL link.

```
do{
            let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "JsonFile", withExtension: "json"); //Get file
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file!); //Get content of file

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]; // Get data as json object

            for data in json["member"] as! [String: Any]{
                print(data.value)


            }

        }catch let err{
            print(err);
        }
```

Output:

```
2017-04-13
Web
000000974
Individual
Active
1656009
a0A2800000PM4DlEAL
Ruby
<img src="https://ap2something
{
    type = "Member__c";
    url = "/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/something";
}
something
0032800000wk79XAAQ
a0B2800000IJPn7EAH
a0P2800000AKJxMEAX
a0G2800000jXisqEAC
```

For URL you can use below example

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: "some url") { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil{ //If error has some value then return
                        print(error);
                        return;
                    }

                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any];
                        for data in json["member"] as! [String: Any]{
                            print(data.value)
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: I want to get the member details. So now since I got a response, I know credentials are taken and they are right. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Is your JSON file okey?  And do you want to read it from file or URL?

Comment: Yes I had tried something like this too. 
 https://paste.ofcode.org/376r2tFDNzXxEyLG8ybz8bg

I get error Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'.

 Am I missing something? @Bikram

Comment: I found out that your JSON response in not correct. Check your JSON file and the problem should be solved. If this solved your problem then please accept the answer.

Comment: this gave me a pointer to check back my code. You are right, I made a mistake. I didnt copy this answer, but it definitely made me look at the mistake I made. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

```
           if let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            for case let result in json["Key"] {



                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain this? Does it go under this  let task = session.dataTask and "Key" would be say "FirstName" and then I just associate it cell.title?

Comment: which data you want to parse such as : member,contact,contact.

Comment: Yes, before posting here I tried this. I got this error domain=nscocoaerrordomain code=3840 Which is why I wanted an explaination, maybe I missed something.